# How to select both boolean values or one

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a ternary operator as below for a LINQ query as shown

```
 var sub = (SubordinationType == 1) ? (true&false) : false;

var query = from vw in dbContext.vw
                            where (vw.office == FieldOffice && vw.SubAgreement == sub)
                            select vw;
```

Here SubAgreement is a bit field in database I need to select both true and false(0,1) or false(0) based on the ternery how do i achieve this?

Any quick suggestions please.

Comment: `(true&false)` can be simplified to `false`.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I need to be able to select from database rows with both 0 and 1 values

Comment: So... don't filter on SubAgreement. Remove `&& vw.SubAgreement == sub` entirely.

Comment: "I need to be able to select from database rows with both 0 and 1 values" - wouldn't that be all rows where that field is not null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var query = from vw in dbContext.vw
            where vw.office == FieldOffice
            select vw;

if (SubordinationType != 1)
{
    query = query.Where(vw => vw.SubAgreement == false);
}
```

In LINQ it's very easy to add new `where` clauses that are in `&&` with the other clauses (note that it's only easy to add if you want them to be in `&&`, the `||` case is much more complex! :-) )

Comment: This solution has the advantage that it will produce cleaner/faster SQL than solutions that add `Subordination == 1` as a conditional inside of the `where` clause.

Answer (score 6):

I think I get your question.  Your logic is:

- If `Subordination` is 1, `SubAgreement` doesn't matter (true or false)
- If `Subordination` is not 1, `SubAgreement` should be false

hence add another condition:

```
//..
where (vw.office == FieldOffice && (Subordination == 1 || !vw.SubAgreement))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a condition that is true when `SubordinationType` is `1` or when `SubAgreement` is `false`:

```
var query = from vw in dbContext.vw
  where (vw.office == FieldOffice && (SubordinationType == 1 || vw.SubAgreement == false))
  select vw;
```